# Starting from what version WordPress provides own embedded audio player without need a plugin?

Tags: audio

According to **[THIS PAGE](http://en.support.wordpress.com/audio/)** Wordpress now provides own embedded audio player. Does anyone know starting from what version this became available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress 3.6. Wordpress also features a video player as well, so no need for plugins anymore

- [Audio / Video support in Core](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/04/08/audio-video-support-in-core/)